# What is the coarsest topology T' on $\mathbf{R}$ s.t. that the following map is continuous?

Tags: general-topology

Let $T$ be the standard topology on $\mathbf{R}$. What is then the coarsest topology such that $f: (\mathbf{R}, T') \rightarrow (\mathbf{R}, T)$ defined by $x \mapsto x^2$ is continuous? Is it the weak topology?

Answer (score 4):

Let $a<b$ and consider the following cases:

1. If $a\geq 0$ then $f^{-1}(a,b) = (-\sqrt{b},-\sqrt{a})\cup (\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b})$.
2. If $b\leq 0$ then $f^{-1}(a,b) = \emptyset$.
3. If $a<0<b$ then $f^{-1}(a,b) = f^{-1}([0,b)) = (-\sqrt{b},\sqrt{b})$.

Thus in order to $f$ to be continuous we need not every usual open set of $\mathbb{R}$ but every symmetric usual open set, that is all usual open sets $U$ such that $-U=U$.

So you can try to prove that 
$$
T' = \{U\subseteq\mathbb{R} : U \text{ is open in the usual topology of }\mathbb{R} \text{ and } U=-U\},
$$
by using, for example, the fact that every open set $U$ in the usual topology of $\mathbb{R}$ equals the disjoint union of an at most countable collection of open intervals.

Also, the coarsest topology on a set $X$ such that a map $f:X\to Y$ is continuous, where $Y$ is a topological space is by definition the weak topology on $X$ generated by $f$.

Comment: Isn't $f^{-1}(a,b)$ the set of points $x$ for which $f(x) \in (a,b)$? So if, for example, $(a,b) = (0,2)$, then according to the above we have $f^{-1}(a,b) = (-2, 0) \cup (0, 2)$. But we have $f(3/2) = 9/4 > 2=b$, so that seems contradictory to me.

Comment: @frej.mh I forgot to write every square root in my answer haha. I hope that with my corrections you agree with my answer.

Comment: Yes I do. Sorry for the nitpicking, just wanted to make sure I hadn't misunderstood something :)

Comment: It's totally ok! Actually I'm a little bit surprised no one else (even the ones who upvoted my anwser) noticed about that mistake. Thank you! :)